LINQ Subquery selects all columns instead of the specified only
I have the following LINQ query:
var query =
       from store in _dbContext.Stores.AsNoTracking()
       join shelf in _dbContext.Shelves.AsNoTracking()
            on store.Id equals shelf.StoreId into storeShelf
       join customers in 
        (
            from customer in _dbContext.Customers.AsNoTracking()
            where customer.IsActive
            select new { customer.Name, customer.shelfId }
        ) on storeShelf.Id equals customers.shelfId into shelfCustomer
       from shelfCustomer2 in shelfCustomer.DefaultIfEmpty()
       select new CompleteModel
       {
           StoreName = store.Name,
           CustomerName = shelfCustomer2.Name
       };

The problem is that the subquery is incorrectly translated. Instead of:
...
SELECT c.Name, c.Age
FROM [dbo].[Customer]
WHERE c.IsActive = 1
...

EF translates to:
...
SELECT c.Id, c.Name, c.Surname, c.Age, c.AddressId, ...
FROM [dbo].[Customer]
WHERE c.IsActive = 1

All columns are selected in the subquery instead of just these two.

What EF version are you using? Could be a bug, can you try with a different version?

@RicardoPeres Version="3.1.32"

It's a very old version, could be related to that. Can't you try it with a newer one?

Additionally, why aren't you just using navigation properties so EF works out the joins itself? EF is designed to remove the need to essentially rewrite SQL statements in Linq.

Even though EF Core 3.x is outdated, it should still handle the following LINQ query correctly:
var query =
    from store in _dbContext.Stores
    join shelf in _dbContext.Shelves on store.Id equals shelf.StoreId
    from shelfCustomer in _dbContext.Customers
        .Where(c => c.shelfId == shelf.Id && c.IsActive)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new CompleteModel
    {
        StoreName = store.Name,
        CustomerName = shelfCustomer.Name
    };

Please note that I have removed AsNoTracking() because it is redundant when using projections. Additionally, AsNoTracking() only needs to be applied once in a query.

Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. Eventually, I decided to create the view.

Can you explain why it do not work for you? Creating view for this simple LINQ is overkill.

Because it still includes all columns in SELECT subquery. The example above is not my production query. Tomorrow I will type sth similar to production code.

Well, all columns in select subquery, but not in result query should not have performance impact. Analyse difference, EF is still bad in complex queries.

Yep, but there is a specific index in the database that improves the query's performance very much. And it's not applied when all columns are selected in the subquery.

Anyway, I'm the author of the extension linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore, it will execute right SQL. It may help in such situations.
